# Query to display specific employee names who are present only one month but not in other months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a sql query to display name of employees who are present "only in january" but not in feb,mar and april.

Here are the table details...

```
create table Employee(Id numeric(18,0),Name varchar(255),Date date);

insert into Employee values(101,'Shiva','2018/01/01'),
                           (102,'Vamsi','2018/01/01'),
                           (103,'Rajesh','2018/01/01'),
                           (104,'Krishna','2018/01/01'),
                           (105,'Tarun','2018/02/01'),
                           (101,'Shiva','2018/02/01'),
                           (103,'Rajesh','2018/02/01'),
                           (106,'Kaala','2018/03/02'),
                           (107,'Azeez','2018/03/02'),
                           (103,'Rajesh','2018/03/02'),
                           (108,'Eswar','2018/04/02'),
                           (109,'Dora','2018/04/02'),
                           (110,'Akash','2018/04/02'),
                           (103,'Rajesh','2018/04/02');
```

Expected result should be as following:

Vamsi

Krishna

Hope i'll get answer from you very soon
Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you usign? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select Name from Employee where MONTH(date)=1
```

[more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you could try something like this. Here I select all employees that do not have a row where the month is not january.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Employee
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Employee WHERE date_part('month', Date) != 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use aggregation.  If you only have data from one year:

```
select name
from Employee
group by name
having month(min(date)) = month(max(date)) and 
       month(min(date)) = 1;
```

If you want only January 2018:

```
select name
from Employee
group by name
having min(date) >= '2018-01-01' and
       max(date) < '2018-02-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Id,Name,[Date]
FROM
(
SELECT *, 
      COUNT(Name)OVER(Partition by Name,DATEPART(YEAR,[date])  ORDER BY id) 
      AS EmpOnlyOnceInMonth
FROM EmployeeData
)dt 
WHERE EmpOnlyOnceInMonth=1 AND DATEPART(M,dt.[date])=1
ORDER BY Id
```

Result

```
Id   Name     Date
----------------------
102  Vamsi   2018-01-01
104  Krishna 2018-01-01
```